# Change ampersand separator with parencite command in APA style

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm using `biblatex-apa` to format citations and reference list. I would like to change `&` separator to `and` when using `parencite` citation command, e.g.:

- `\parencite{ref1}` --> (author and author, 2013)
- `\parencite{ref2}` --> (author, author and author, 2014)

I already successfully re-declare delimiter in the reference list using the commands:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
      {}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
         {\finalandcomma\addspace{}and\space}
         {\addspace{}and\space}}}}
```

but have no idea how to change separator for citations. Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,hyperref]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{ref1,
    author    = {Guyon, Isabelle and Elisseeff, Andr\'{e}},
    journal   = {The Journal of Machine Learning Research},
    pages     = {1157--1182},
    title     = {{An introduction to variable and feature selection}},
    volume    = {3},
    year      = {2003}
}
@book{ref2,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite{ref1}, consectetur adipiscing elit \parencite{ref2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it only for `\parencite` citations or all citations? Also, an MWE would be greatly appreciated, so we can just try away our ideas for solutions, and don't have to set up a new document ourselves. Am I right in thinking you want "and" in citations *and* the bibliography as well?

Comment: Actually, for all citations, but especially for `\parencite` command. I'm working on MWE.

Comment: OK, my point was that `\parencite` is not to be treated differently from the other cite commands.

Comment: I posted the MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Newer versions of `biblatex`/`biblatex-apa` have a more sophisticated delimiter mechanism. This solution won't work there any more, please see [author separator with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439434/35864).

`biblatex-apa` changes the `\finalnamedelim` quite often, so the best solution seems to be to restore the wanted delimiter definition for each citation and at the beginning of the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,hyperref]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
      {}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
         {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
         {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
      {}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
         {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
         {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite{companion}, consectetur adipiscing elit \parencite{baez/article}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: Not working for me... I still get the ampersands. Compiled with ``pdflatex`` and using updated ``texlive 2018``. Your code with the OP's references here: https://pastebin.com/yQvcbQAX

Comment: @PatrickT `biblatex` has gotten a new context-sensitive delimiter interface in the meantime. Things work differently now. Maybe you should ask a new question about that.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks moewe. Here is my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439434/author-separator-with-biblatex